# 500 error when calling Devops Pipeline runs api via REST API call from another pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-pipelines-tasks

In my Azure Devops Pipeline, I'm using `InvokeRESTAPI@1` to trigger another Devops Pipeline by POSTing to the pipeline run endpoint documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0).

This used to work, but as of August 4 2023 I'm getting a 500 error when this pipeline runs. I can still call successfully from Postman using the same PAT credentials. I also upgraded from api `v6.0-preview` to `v7.0` with no difference.

I've seen a couple of Q&A's reporting similar 500 errors, but those were due to some issue from either the calling side or the pipeline being called, which is not the case here.

Pipeline code:

```
  - task: InvokeRESTAPI@1
    displayName: Call Pipeline 2
    inputs:
      connectionType: 'connectedServiceName'
      serviceConnection: "<My Service Connection (using PAT)>"
      method: 'POST'
      body: '{
          "resources": { "repositories": { "self": { "refName": "refs/heads/$(Build.SourceBranchName)" } } },
          "templateParameters": { "boolParam": true, "stringParam": "stringVal" }
        }'
      urlSuffix: '/ProjectName/_apis/pipelines/${{parameters.pipelineId}}/runs?api-version=7.0'
      waitForCompletion: 'false'
```

Error (rendered from html returned to the pipeline logs):
[image: Error]